# Having trouble with a PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Okay, lets say I have the following text...

```
<h2><a name="test1"></a>Test 1</h2>test 1 text
<h2><a name="test2"></a>Test 2</h2>
test 2 text
<h3><a name="test3"></a>Test 3</h3>
test
3
text
<h4><a name="test4"></a>Test 4</h4>
<h4><a name="test5"></a>Test 5</h4>test 5 text
```

I would like to use regular expressions to replace that text with the following:

```
<div class="toggle">
    <h2><a name="test1"></a>Test 1</h2>
    <div class="contents">test 1 text</div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
    <h2><a name="test1"></a>Test 2</h2>
    <div class="contents">test 2 text</div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
    <h3><a name="test1"></a>Test 3</h3>
    <div class="contents">test
3
text</div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
    <h4><a name="test1"></a>Test 4</h4>
    <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
    <h4><a name="test1"></a>Test 5</h4>
    <div class="contents">test 5 text</div>
</div>
```

I tried using:

```
$text = preg_replace('#<h(\d+)>(.*?)</h\1>(.*)#si', '<div class="ToggleContents"><h$1>$2</h$1><div class="contents">$3</div></div>', $text);
```

But the problem with this is that it's far too greedy and I haven't figured out how to make it ungreedy and work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why not use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of a regex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Can you modify the <a href> code to : <h2><a name="test1"></a>Test 1</h2><span>test 1 text</span> for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out... I just appended ##### to all headers, and seeked to that.

```
$page['HTML'] = preg_replace('#(<h(\d+)>)#i', '#####$1', $page['HTML']);
$page['HTML'] = preg_replace(
        '#<h(\d+)>(.*?)</h\1>(.*?)(\#{5}|$)#si',
        '<div class="ToggleContents"><h$1>$2</h$1><div class="contents">$3</div></div>',
        $page['HTML']);
$page['HTML'] = preg_replace(
        '#<div class="ToggleContents"><h(\d+)>(.*?)</h\1><div class="contents">([<br\s/>]*?)</div></div>#i',
        '<h$1>$2</h$1>$3',
        $page['HTML']);
$page['HTML'] = str_ireplace('#####', '', $page['HTML']);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = '<h2><a name="test1"></a>Test 1</h2> test 1 text
<h2><a name="test2"></a>Test 2</h2> test 2 text
<h3><a name="test3"></a>Test 3</h3> test 3 text
<h4><a name="test4"></a>Test 4</h4> test 4 text
<h4><a name="test5"></a>Test 5</h4> test 5 text';

$text = preg_replace('#<h([1|2|3|4|5|6])>(.*?)</h([1|2|3|4|5|6])>\ (.*?)(\n|$)#si', '
<div class="toggle">
  <h\\1>\\2</h\\1>
  <div class="contents">\\4</div>
</div>
', $text);
```

Or the `<span>` solution:

```
$text = '<h2><a name="test1"></a>Test 1</h2><span>test 1 text</span>
<h2><a name="test2"></a>Test 2</h2><span>test 2 text</span>
<h3><a name="test3"></a>Test 3</h3><span>test 3 text</span>
<h4><a name="test4"></a>Test 4</h4><span>test 4 text</span>
<h4><a name="test5"></a>Test 5</h4><span>test 5 text</span>';

$text = preg_replace('#<h([1|2|3|4|5|6])>(.*?)</h([1|2|3|4|5|6])><span>(.*?)</span>#si', '
<div class="toggle">
  <h\\1>\\2</h\\1>
  <div class="contents">\\4</div>
</div>
', $text);
```

Comment: thanks... almost works... I've updated my question with a different $text format. How would I get it working now?

Comment: is that code provided be updated? or it needs to be parsed like that?

Comment: the text is in all manner of different formats... sometimes without linebreaks, sometimes with. Updated again. Notice that text 4 doesn't have anything. Basically, you have the dot operator seeking till the next \n. I need the dot operator to seek till the next <h\d+> tag.

Comment: The code has to be parsed as is. It has to seek till the next <h> or $

Comment: does it needs to be a pref_replace? or a preg_match with replace can work?

Comment: if you add these before the preg_replace, it works!

$text = str_replace("\n", ' ', $text);
$text = preg_replace("#</h(\d)>\ #", "</h\\1>", $text);
$text = preg_replace("#<h(\d)>#", "\n<h\\1>", $text);

but it's not the most elegant solution. I think you should parse data before preg_replace (like adding <span>)

Comment: That does work... but it gets rid of existing line breaks. If you look at my first post at "test 3" results, you can see that I need the line breaks to be maintained. Editing the source text is not possible; which is why I have to do it in regex.

Answer (score 1):

Split it into three different search and replace operations?